# My array is not summing the elements of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, razor

I have an array being populated with doubles(DataType) that are the result of calculations using data from SQL. The array has the numbers I need and is to my knowledge being populated correctly. The problem is that my sum variable is not doing the addition.

```
double[]  _array1 =  new double[]
            {
Foo = SQLdata1 - SQLdata2 - SQLdata3 };


        foreach (var j in array1)
        {
            Response.Write(j.ToString("c"));

            sum =+ j;

        } <td>@sum.ToString("C")</td>
```

I've tried this a number of ways. This is the most recent. This is only displaying the last number of the array. I'm not using a list or LINQ because the data is not in the database. The information being displayed is done at runtime. My question is could it be possible I'm not iterating through correctly? I'm Lost on what exactly is happening and why sum is not working. The response.write method shows the contents of the array correctly.

Comment: Does `_array1` == `array1`?

Comment: yes actually. This was a typo  they are both _array1

Answer (score 2):

> This is only displaying the last number of the array.

Your code has the line

```
sum =+ j;
```

which is the same as

```
sum = +j;
```

which sets `sum` to `j`.

---

The line should instead be

```
sum += j;
```

---

Also - in your code, as it is at the moment, there is only one value in the array, `Foo`:

```
double[]  _array1 =  new double[]
{
    Foo = SQLdata1 - SQLdata2 - SQLdata3
};
```

That array has only one item. Trivially, the sum of one item is that item.

Comment: I'm still only getting the last value

Comment: If there is only one value in the array then the sum will be equal to that value.

Comment: True but Response. Write shows all of the elements from the array which are the correct elements.

Comment: var s = _array1[j]; Response.Write(s.ToString("c"));

            sum += s;

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting updated code as a comment - that way, people reading the question the first time will see it.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my answer. I simply removed sum= 0 from a portion of the code above. I'm also using `for(int j = _array1.GetLowerBound(0); j <= _array1.GetUpperBound(0); j++)` as opposed to .length